# apache proxy HTTPS to HTTP with POST data

Tags: linux, apache, mod-proxy

I have mobile a app uploading to https://mydomain.com/files/incoming_files.php and https://mydomain.com/api/v2/incoming_files.php

Ubuntu 11.04, Apache/2.2.17

Some of the uploads times out in the SSL handshake.
Therefore I'm trying to proxy POST upload requests to the PHP upload scripts from https:// to http:// and keep the POST data.

Throws these errors:

```
  (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: prefetch request body failed to   1.2.3.4:80
  (103)Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed to 1.2.3.4:80
   proxy: pass request body failed to 1.2.3.4:80
```

This is my config:

```
   <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
   RewriteRule ^/?files/incoming_files\.php http://%{SERVER_NAME}/files/incoming_files\.php [NC,P]
   RewriteRule ^/?api/v2/incoming_files\.php http://%{SERVER_NAME}/api/v2/incoming_files\.php [NC,P]


   SSLProxyEngine on
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   SetEnv proxy-sendchunked       1
   SetEnv proxy-sendcl            0

   ProxyPass /files/incoming_files.php http://mydomain.com/files/incoming_files.php
   ProxyPassReverse /files/incoming_files.php http://mydomain.com/files/incoming_files.php

   ProxyPass /api/v2/incoming_files.php http://mydomain.com/api/v2/incoming_files.php
   ProxyPassReverse /api/v2/incoming_files.php http://mydomain.com/api/v2/incoming_files.php
```

Have tried to: Set Rewrite without ProxyPass. Set ProxyPass without Rewrite. Set with/without SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1/proxysend-cl 0

Any idea what the best solution is, and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same error messages in my apache access log:

```
[error] (103)Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed to X.X.X.X:Y (hostname)
[error] proxy: pass request body failed to X.X.X.X:Y (hostname) from Z.Z.Z.Z ()
```

with the only difference seeming to be that I'm running a tcServer (Tomcat) backend.

What I can tell you is that I'm also seeing a 502 response code associated with the upload request.

```
"POST /<path_to_target>/upload.do?_t=1407181458532 HTTP/1.1" 502 305
```

I think you might be on to something with the fact that your ProxyPass is redirecting HTTPS to HTTP and that is something I need to test.

One thing I would suggest is that you change update the ProxyRequests value to On.

```
ProxyRequests On
```